# How to fix windows escape characters not working correctly in python?

Tags: python, windows, escaping, textcolor

I am currently trying to get python to show colored text in the windows terminal. Unfortunately, the escape sequence is not being interpreted correctly.

At first, I tried to use different libraries including "crayons", "termcolor" and "colorama". Unfortunately, these show similar problems to my code.

```py
print(str('\033[31m' + 'this should be red'))
```

The output should be the text "this should be red", but in red instead of the standard white. The actual output is "[31msome red text", in white and with a weird special character showcased as a box with a question mark in it at the start.

Comment: The example `print` call should work with colorama. Did you enable it via `colorama.init()`?

Comment: When using Fore.RED in  colorama, I get "NameError: name 'Fore' is not defined"

Comment: So I started specifying to import "Fore,Style,Back" and it finally works, but is there any explanation why these don't get imported when importing the module as a whole? Doesn't python automatically import everything from the module?

Comment: An import sets a reference to the module in the importing namespace. If the module isn't already cached in `sys.modules`, an import also instantiates the module object and compiles its code as bytecode (if not already cached in a .pyc file) and executes it in the module's dict namespace. You can change the imported module name, e.g. `import colorama as color`. Or if you want a shallow copy of its public namespace (or whatever it defines in `__all__`), you can use `from colorama import *`. However, both practices are discouraged.

Comment: If you call `colorama.init()`, it modifies `sys.stdout` to support common virtual terminal escapes, so you can simply use `print('\033[31m' + 'this should be red')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment by eryksun: colorama.init() modifies sys.stdout in such a way that the output is displyed correctly in color.